# How to calulate the difference between a MySQL timestamp and the current time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to calculate the difference between a timestamp retrieved from a MySQL database and the current time.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: -1: After we already told you in the chat what to try and linking you to http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+calculate+timestamp+difference and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html you should not have any need to ask your own question.

Comment: It's not clear if you mean timestamp or unix_timestamp.

Comment: Why is this tagged Zend-Framework?

Comment: Because I didn't want answers that involve raw SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @RemoteSojourner, I got the current time in a UNIX timestamp format (which returns time in seconds), I got the timestamp from the DB (using an ORM) and converted that to a UNIX timstamp too and then subtracted the two timestamps.

```
            $current_time = strtotime("now");
            $last_access_time = strtotime($this->last_access);
            $inactivity_duration = $current_time - $last_access_time;
```

Answer (score 1):

This example makes the difference between now and one hour ago.

select timediff(now(), now() - interval 1 hour)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the strtotime function to parse the MySQL timestamp into a Unix timestamp can be further parsed or formatted in the PHP date function.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the datetime from mysql like this

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_col`) FROM `tablename`...
```

AND compare it to `time()`

Comment: Ahh, I was assuming (from the php + zend tags) that you wanted to compare in php